# Adding new tables -- memory usage increases

Tags: mysql, innodb, memory

I added more tables to my mysql server. 20% increase in tables that are all innodb. I have 200 + databases that use the same schema.

Does adding more tables increase memory usage? I am using about 1.7 gb of ram for mysql where before I was using 1.4-1.5gb

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having? You've configured mysql to use a certain amount of memory and it's using it. Do you want to restrict the amount if data cached?

Comment: Yes, I want to use less memory without impacting performance a lot. It started using more memory as soon as I added more tables. I didn't change anything in my.cnf so I am stumped on why it would go up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it increase memory ??? Absolutely !!!

I wrote a post about INFORMATION_SCHEMA (`Jun 15, 2011` : [How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336))

In that post I explained how metadata for MySQL tables are stored in temporary tables using the MEMORY storage engine. For example, when you create a table `mydb.mytable`, look at what gets populated into these tables:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html) (One row for `mydb.mytable`)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitions-table.html) (If `mydb.mytable` is partitioned, one row for each partition)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/columns-table.html) Info about every column in `mydb.mytable`
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/statistics-table.html) : Information about index statistics in `mydb.mytable`
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/key-column-usage-table.html) : Information about a column's use in all indexes in `mydb.mytable`
- See the [full list of INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/information-schema.html)

In short, all these tables have to increase in memory usage for each table you create. In your particular case, that would be multiplied by 200.

Comment: do you know how much memory is used for one database with (lets say) 200 tables? It should be very less when no queries on tables (archive for example)?

Comment: @Ivanov Archive tables make the situation magnitudes worse. Right now, I have a client with 11000+ DBs and 1000000+ (1 million tables). The majority of the tables have not been in used in the last 3 months. Trying to run queries against INFORMATION_SCHEMA (which is comprised of MEMORY tables with no indexes (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336)) is a total nightmare. Archive DB should be migrated away to free memory.