# Getting Data Type ID in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So, In SQL, We have the following query to find the system data type ID of columns in SQL Server;

```
select name, system_type_id from sys.columns where object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'sometable')
```

It gives the following output;

```
name       system_type_id
rowid        56
Client       167
IsCurrent    104
```

The system_type_id represents the int value of data type of that column.

Whereas, when I tried to convert (find an equivalent) in MySQL, I couldn't find the ID of column's data type. The following is the query I have managed to find so far;

```
SELECT column_name,data_type FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'someSchema' AND TABLE_NAME = 'someTable';
```

It gives the following output.

```
# column_name,   data_type
    'rowid',      'int'
     'Client',    'varchar'
     'IsCurrent', 'tinyint'
```

Any suggestions how I can achieve the earlier output in MySQL ?

Comment: Aren't the `int, varchar, tinyint` good for you? Why do you need some numbers instead?

Comment: @ypercube I actually have to incorporate this query into a .net application and currently I am using numbers. I will change the code once people here tell me that's impossible.

Comment: I don't think that mysql exposes any internal numbers/codes to information schema.

Comment: Such is the cost of porting from one brand of RDBMS to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discussed [How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336) about 4 years ago.

SQL and PostgreSQL have ObjectID enumeration (oid) of object types. MySQL made the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database a more simplified representation of table, column, and index metadata. The metadata tables are temporary MEMORY tables with no indexes.

Last year in [Adding new tables -- memory usage increases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63591/adding-new-tables-memory-usage-increases/63593#63593) I discussed what happens to memory with the INFORMATION_SCHEMA does when you increase the number of tables.

Believe me, adding an `oid` for data types to the MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA would just bloat the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. In this particular instance, I greatly appreciate MySQL not having oid values exposed.

If you really want to learn about how mysql represents data types under the hood I refer you to [pages 48-53 of "Understanding MySQL Internals" (ISBN 0-596-00957-7)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009577).

[image: MySQL Internals]

Those pages refer to `sql/table.h` and `sql/field.h` in the source code. You can download the source code and look it over. Then, judge for yourself how and why oid is not included.

## SUGGESTION

Create your own. For example, to make oids for columns do this

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS my_metadata;
CREATE DATABASE my_metadata;
USE metadata
CREATE TABLE objects ENGINE=MEMORY
SELECT data_type FROM information_schema.columns WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE objects ADD COLUMN oid INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE objects ADD UNIQUE INDEX (data_type);
INSERT INTO objects (data_type)
SELECT DISTINCT data_type FROM information_schema.columns;
```