# 'mysql' database in fresh MySQL installation

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I installed MySQL database and according to `show databases` command I have a database named 'mysql'. Is this database used for holding some internal values for MySQL? In addition, is it possible to view the content of rows of tables in 'mysql' database? Usual `SELECT * FROM tablename` does not seem to work:

```
mysql> describe servers;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Server_name | char(64) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Host        | char(64) | NO   |     |         |       |
| Db          | char(64) | NO   |     |         |       |
| Username    | char(64) | NO   |     |         |       |
| Password    | char(64) | NO   |     |         |       |
| Port        | int(4)   | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| Socket      | char(64) | NO   |     |         |       |
| Wrapper     | char(64) | NO   |     |         |       |
| Owner       | char(64) | NO   |     |         |       |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT * FROM servers;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql.servers` table is used only in conjunction with any table that uses the FEDERATED Storage Engine. [It's in the MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/federated-usagenotes.html):

> FEDERATED tables may be replicated to other slaves, but you must ensure that the slave servers are able to use the user/password combination that is defined in the CONNECTION string (or the row in the mysql.servers table) to connect to the remote server.

Therefore, a freshly installed MySQL instance will have `mysql.servers` empty. If you create a FEDERATED table, then the username/password for a remote table is populated in `mysql.servers`.

What you are looking for is the information_schema database. For example,

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/schemata-table.html) has all the databases in the MySQL Instance
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) has all the tables in the MySQL Instance
- Please Read the Following

  - [MySQL Documentation on INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-schema.html)
  - My 4-Year-Old Post [How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336)