# Why tmp tables created when connected to one database

Tags: mysql, temporary-tables

I am wondering why temp tables created while switching to database. When I login to the mysql server, I have queried current session temp tables as follows:

```
mysql> show status like '%tmp%';  
+-------------------------+-------+  
| Variable_name           | Value |  
+-------------------------+-------+  
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 0     |  
| Created_tmp_files       | 6     |  
| Created_tmp_tables      | 0     |  
+-------------------------+-------+  

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> \u database_name  
Reading table information for completion of table and column names  
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A  

Database changed  

mysql> show status like '%tmp%';  

+-------------------------+-------+  
| Variable_name           | Value |  
+-------------------------+-------+  
| Created_tmp_disk_tables | 0     |  
| Created_tmp_files       | 6     |  
| Created_tmp_tables      | 3     |  
+-------------------------+-------+  
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea why were 3 temp tables created ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the message

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A
```

Table info is being read from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Why ?

According to the [MySQL Documentation on auto rehashing for the mysql client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_auto-rehash):

> --auto-rehash
>
> Enable automatic rehashing. This option is on by default, which
>   enables database, table, and column name completion. Use
>   --disable-auto-rehash to disable rehashing. That causes mysql to start faster, but you must issue the rehash command or its # shortcut if
>   you want to use name completion.
>
> To complete a name, enter the first part and press Tab. If the name is
>   unambiguous, mysql completes it. Otherwise, you can press Tab again to
>   see the possible names that begin with what you have typed so far.
>   Completion does not occur if there is no default database.

For your session, internal temp tables with info from INFORMATION_SCHEMA is needed for hitting the tab character in the event multiple columns or multiple tables have the same prefix characters.

## CAVEAT

Please note that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database is comprised of temp tables to begin with : See my post [How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336).

Therefore, it should be no surprise that more temp tables are created to hold table and column info for a database you just switched to. This is particularly true if you are not a super user like `root@localhost` and your grants only go as high as the database level.

Comment: Why these internal temp tables are created(when switched to one database) when we already have information_schema tables which are temporary tables and having meta data. Its redundant right . I have checked the "How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?". But i have seen some of the information_schema tables are created with myisam storage engine but not memory . Examples: COLUMNS ,EVENTS.

Comment: `Auto-rehash` predates `information_schema`; I can't imagine how it has _anything_ to do with the OP's question.

Comment: I have checked the behavior by disabling auto-rehash on mysql client command line using -A option ,Created_tmp_tables count did not increased to 3.It stands on zero itself.

Comment: James,please let me know whether my understanding is correct or not here. As i commented earlier , Some information_schema tables are Myisam (ex:columns,events) but not using memory storage engine. As you mentioned in previous answer ,these table used memory storage engine first ,but due to some constraints they switched to myisam. Am i right?

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons for tmp tables.  Let's look at some from `SELECT`:

- `GROUP BY` sometimes need to collect the data, sort it, then do the grouping.
- `ORDER BY` ditto
- `GROUP BY one_thing ORDER BY something_else` definitely needs to sort, hence a tmp table.
- `UNION` *always* (until very recently) used a tmp table.  (Now it is smarter about whether tmp is needed.)
- subqueries might need a tmp table, especially `FROM ( SELECT ... )`
- `IN ( SELECT ... )` probably needs one in 5.6; previously it would re-evaluate the query repeatedly.

Note that *one* `SELECT` might need multiple tmp tables.  This is OK.

`Created_tmp_tables` counts tmp tables, whether `MEMORY` or `MyISAM`; `Created_tmp_disk_tables` counts only the latter.  `MEMORY` is preferred (faster), but there are restrictions (datatypes, size, etc) that lead to either starting out with `MyISAM` or converting to it when the tmp table exceeds `max_heap_table_size` and `tmp_table_size` (after trying to use `MEMORY`).

Comment: you are absolutely right james . The scenario you explained is when you fire some queries on database using group by,order by etc. But i haven't fired anything, i just redirected to one database. So whats the purpose of temp tables here.

Comment: Hmmm... No increased value for me:  `SHOW... \u... SHOW`.  You are not using `FEDERATED`, I assume?

Comment: Maybe something to do with the `VARIABLES` `innodb_stats...`.  (I turned on `innodb_stats_on_metadata`, but it still did not happen for me.)  What version are you running?

Comment: i am running on mysql 5.5.40

Comment: I am not using federated storage engine