# why has Lock_time in slow query log when execute select sql?

Tags: mysql

Why mysql has Lock_time in slow query log when execute select sql?

> Time: 2018-11-22T15:06:32.654503Z
>    User@Host: root[root] @ localhost
>    []  Id:     3
>    Query_time: 0.058138  Lock_time: 0.000287 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 3115 SET timestamp=1542899192;
>   select * from COLUMNS where COLUMN_TYPE ='int';

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, MySQL has a read lock, probably to deliver consistent results.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the query, my guess is that you are looking up all the defined columns in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` that are defined as `INT`.

The reason why there was a lock on `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` ???

The table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is defined as a temporary memory table. Memory tables undergo full tables locks when being accessed for change (such as when one does `ALTER TABLE` or `CREATE TABLE`) from anywhere in the database,

Here is an excerpt from my old post [How is INFORMATION_SCHEMA implemented in MySQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3335/how-is-information-schema-implemented-in-mysql/3336#3336)

> All tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA database are stored directly in memory as MEMORY storage engine tables. They are totally internal to MySQL, so the .frm mechanisms are handled in mysqld. In my answer, I first showed the table layout of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES. **It is a temporary table in memory. It is manipulated using storage engine protocols.** Thus, when mysqld is shutdown, all information_schema tables are dropped. When mysqld is started, all information_schema tables are created as TEMPORARY tables and repopulated with metadata for every table in the mysql instance.

Please note what is in bold

> It is a temporary table in memory. It is manipulated using storage engine protocols.

When you look up the [MEMORY storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html) in the Docs, it shows that Lock Granularity is Table. So, every table in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, including `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` will received a lock at some point, EVEN FOR A SELECT (just like a MyISAM table).

Comment: (MySQL 8.0's Data Dictionary changes all of this.  It will now be an InnoDB table lookup.)